# Block the use of @everyone

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I made a command for my bot to say whatever the user types when they type `!botsay ___` but I don't know the best way to stop people from using `@everyone` in the command. I need help figuring out what I can do to fix up my code.

Here's my current code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def botsay(ctx, *args):
    mesg = ' '.join(args)
    await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)
    if "@everyone" in message.content:
        await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)
        await bot.say("You may not tag everyone/here in this command, "+ctx.message.author.mention)
    else:
        return
        await bot.say(mesg)
        return
```

Comment: What is currently happening when using your code? Does it give an error? Is there no error but the bot does nothing? Does the bot ignore your `if` and posts the message?

Comment: I think deleting the same message twice will raise an exception.  remove the two `return`s, the first prevents everything after it from being executed and the second is useless.

Comment: You can also more easily gather the "remainder" of a command using the signature `async def botsay(ctx, *, mesg)`

Comment: When I run it the command, the bot simply deletes the message and doesn't say what follows

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work. It's written in the latest version of discord.py and the latest version of Python.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    messageText = message.content

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    elif '@everyone' in messageText:
        messageText.replace('@everyone', '[REDACTED']

    else:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, text)
```

Comment: This is not the most recent version of `discord.py`.  The most recent version is version 1.0, also called the rewrite branch.  This is written in version 0.16, the async branch.  [`Client.send_message` does not exist in the rewrite branch](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html#sending-messages). The rewrite branch isn't officially stable yet, which is what has led to your confusion, but enough people use it for this to be misleading.  (IMO the release has been pretty badly mismanaged)

Comment: message is not defined?

Answer (score 0):

Other than what Patrick Haugh said in the comments (which I incorporated them in this answer); in case you hadn't caught up to the comments, your problem's caused by multiple `delete_message` and you returned the function before actually sending the success message.

I think it's worth to know that there's an attribute that checks if the message mentions everyone:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def botsay(ctx, *, msg):
    await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)
    if message.mention_everyone:
        await bot.say("You may not tag everyone/here in this command, "+ctx.message.author.mention)
    else:
        await bot.say(msg)
```

From the docs:

> **`mention_everyone`** *bool* – Specifies if the message mentions everyone.
>
> **Note:**
>
> > This does not check if the `@everyone` text is in the message
> >     itself. Rather this boolean indicates if the `@everyone` text is in the
> >     message and it did end up mentioning everyone.